# Jenkins sends wrong build status to stash

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using jenkins with the pipeline plugin, the XUnitBuilder plugin and the stash notifier plugin. I have the problem that it reports the wrong build status. My pipeline:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            parallel(
                failFast: true,
                'One': {
                    node( 'windows' ){
                        run tests ...
                        step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder',
                             thresholds: [
                                [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '0', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '0', unstableThreshold: '0']
                            ],
                            tools: [
                                [$class: 'CTestType', deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: 'Testing/**/Test.xml']
                            ]
                        ])
                    }
                },

                'Two': {
                    node( 'windows' ){
                        run tests ...
                        step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder',
                             thresholds: [
                                [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureNewThreshold: '0', failureThreshold: '0', unstableNewThreshold: '0', unstableThreshold: '0']
                            ],
                            tools: [
                                [$class: 'CTestType', deleteOutputFiles: true, failIfNotNew: true, pattern: 'Testing/**/Test.xml']
                            ]
                        ])
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

Problem: As soon as 'One' is finished, the XUnitBuilder sets the build result to success which is reported to stash and my pull request can be merged. This is obviously wrong since 'Two' may be not even started.
I need to
* prevent the XUnitPublisher from setting the build result if it is success or
* prevent stash from being notified before the whole pipeline finished

Sure, i could stash the test results and run the XUnitBuilder in a post section but this is getting quite complicated since my pipeline has several stages each with several parallel steps running tests.

Does anyone know hot to fix this?

Comment: How are you setting up the stash notifier plugin ? I believe it can be triggered in the pipeline by step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])  and it will send the currentBuild.result

Comment: Yes it can be triggered but if the build result is success (set by XUniBuilder) there is no way to reset it to inprogress. For the stash notifier plugin there already is a discussion that the jenkins pipeline result states are different than he stash build states and they should be decoupled...

Comment: so you are saying that the parallel step continues before 'two' completes ? that seem to be a bug in Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: No really, both steps are scheduled in parallel and the pipeline only continues after both steps finished successfully. But e.g. "one" takes 10 minutes while "Two" takes 5 seconds, then as soon as "two" is finished, the pipeline result is set to success and stash allows me to merge my pull request while infact "one" is still running and might fail. Same happens in "one" finishes first or the wo jobs are executed sequentially because of few build slaves....